# Is there a way to declare and instantly run function?

Tags: javascript, function

I've a code:

```
var myFn = function(){
  //some code
}
myFn();
```

So I have to define a function, then run it in two rows.
Is there a way to define a function (with storage it in variable) and run it instantly, in one expression? Just a short way of this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Comment: Yes, add a couple of parenthesis after those braces;

Comment: Ummm... why? What problem are you trying to solve here? Usually you either want to declare a function and run it at a different place in code, or you just want to run an anonymous function. If you really want to do this, just follow the usual rules of the language - assignment returns the assigned value, so you can do `(myFn = function() { ... })();`. The original variant is much more readable, though. Are you trying to write obfuscated code? If not, I'd avoid such "shortcuts", and just use a separate declaration and invocation.

Comment: I'd like to have function to call it in other places, but it should be run first time just after creating. Now I write separate declaration and invocation, and want to shorten the code

Answer (score -1):

```
var myFn = function(){
  console.log("test");
}()
```

myFn will be undefined because the function doesn't return anything

Comment: Be careful assigning the result to `myFn` as done here - this will assign the _results_ of executing the function to `myFn`, rather than the function itself (as in the original question)

Comment: oh didn't know that..interesting..thanks